# How can I translate a perl script to Java?

Tags: java, android, perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert OO Perl to Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106736/how-can-i-convert-oo-perl-to-java)

Hello.

I have a perl script and I want to translate it to Java.

Is there any translator/conversor from perl script to Java?

By the way, I'm developing an Android 2.2 application.

**EDIT**
I have closed the question. Stop downvoting me!!!!!! And if you downvote tell us why!!

Thanks.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler: I see you are not absolutly sure if my question is a duplicate of other. -1 vote is yours?

Comment: @VansFannel no, I didn't downvote, I voted to close. I don't think it's a bad question, I just think it's been answered before.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler: Before post my question, I have read the other question. I don't this question is duplicated. Thanks for your info.

Comment: Thank you very much for someone that has downvote me and hasn't said why.

Comment: @VansFennel  The message from Rafe Kettler is the automated message that gets posted when you vote to close for a duplicate question.  The question mentioned is indeed the same as your question... how do you convert form perl to Java?  If you think your question is unique, you need to add additional specific information to that regard.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3399781/why-is-it-not-possible-to-create-a-practical-perl-to-python-source-code-converter which has to do with perl->python, but the answer is the same

Comment: I have closed the question. Stop downvoting me!!!!!!!!

Comment: People continue downvoting and none say why. Thansk a lot! I will learn a lot with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should consider using the [Android Scripting Environment](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) so that you can just use your Perl script rather than having to "translate" it to Java (especially if you plan on relying on some translation tool to do it).

It supports Perl, along with Python, Ruby, and some others.

Comment: Doesn't ASE require a special runtime in order to work?

Answer (score 2):

Just my two cents...

I would convert the Perl to Java by hand that way you are 100% in control of the Java code running in your Android application and that way you will understand what the Perl code is actually doing rather than relying on it to work when there is a bug in your Android app.

Answer (score 0):

No. There's the JPL project from the 90's that might've been a workaround, but I'm pretty sure it fell apart along the road.